Restricting number of trend tests reported from ordered factors in R
In this post is an answer that shows a neat trick for restricting the default polynomial tests of trend embedded within ordered factors in R
Here's some toy data
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(f_ord = factor(x = rep(letters[1:5],each=5),
                               ordered = TRUE),
                f_nonOrd = factor(x = rep(letters[1:5],each=5),
                                  ordered = FALSE),
                score = as.vector(sapply(seq(0,20,5), function(i) rnorm(n=5,i,2))))

summary(lm(score ~ f_ord, data = d))

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  9.51644    0.39938  23.828 3.72e-16 ***
# f_ord.L     16.26384    0.89304  18.212 6.40e-14 ***
# f_ord.Q     -0.11831    0.89304  -0.132    0.896    
# f_ord.C     -0.44290    0.89304  -0.496    0.625    
# f_ord^4     -0.09876    0.89304  -0.111    0.913 

So that's the default output returned by specifying the ordered version of the predictor. And here's how to cherry pick the polynomials we want and exclude the rest using the contr.poly() function, for example say we only wanted the quadratic and quarternary trend tests, we could do the following
contrasts(x = d$f_nonOrd,2) <- contr.poly(5)[, c(2,4)]

summary(lm(score ~ f_nonOrd, data = d))

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  9.51644    1.59732   5.958 5.38e-06 ***
# f_nonOrd.Q  -0.11831    3.57173  -0.033    0.974    
# f_nonOrd^4  -0.09876    3.57173  -0.028    0.978 

So far so good, two coefficients, one for quadratic, one for quarternary. My problem is that I only want to see the linear trend test. But when I do
contrasts(x = d$f_nonOrd) <- contr.poly(5)[, 1]

and then run the regression
summary(lm(score ~ f_nonOrd, data = d))

I get
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  9.51644    0.39938  23.828 3.72e-16 ***
# f_nonOrd1   16.26384    0.89304  18.212 6.40e-14 ***
# f_nonOrd2   -0.06628    0.89304  -0.074    0.942    
# f_nonOrd3    0.23780    0.89304   0.266    0.793    
# f_nonOrd4   -0.39871    0.89304  -0.446    0.660

Why am I getting four coefficients instead of the one I asked for? And does anyone know a way to limit it to the one linear trend coefficient?

I think you should look into spearman correlation. It‘s probably better suited to answer your actual question.

You forgot to specify "how many":
contrasts(x = d$f_nonOrd, how.many=1) <- contr.poly(5)[, 1]
Call:
lm(formula = score ~ f_nonOrd, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9217 -1.1534 -0.5023  1.1166  5.1722 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.5164     0.3750   25.38  < 2e-16 ***
f_nonOrd1    16.2638     0.8385   19.40 9.42e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.875 on 23 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9424,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9399 
F-statistic: 376.2 on 1 and 23 DF,  p-value: 9.418e-16

